# Regex for validating path

Tags: regex, regular-language

How do I write a regex that passes for below conditions in C#

\segment\segment\

a) each segment starts and ends with a backslash

b) segment can be alpha-numeric with dashes, underscore and period allowed (e.g. \some-name\some.other_name\ )

c) the sequence can repeat max 100 times (basically only 100 segments allowed)

Comment: What should NOT be matched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex("^\\(?:[\w\-.]+\\){1,100}$");
```

The regex starts with matching '\', then matches letters, digits, underscore, hyphens, dots one or more times, ending with a '\'. It finally repeats this one to 100 times.

This version supports unicode path names.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
(?<=\\)[A-Za-z\-\.]+(?=\\)
```

to select any combination of characters you mentioned within the backslashes? Not selecting the backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

The following is Extended Regular Expressions (ERE). Add any other allowed characters (notably I believe space may be a character you want in, ensuring that the - is left at the end) between the square brackets:

```
^(\\[\w.-]+){1,100}\\$
```

(after correcting for a bug in the code, the resulting code is the same as the answer above haha!)